# Why is the Indirect Function Behaving Erratically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've attached photos with a detailed explanation and composite screencaps of my labors thus far.

[image: Step-by-step process + diagnostic attempts]

[image: Further attempts at troubleshooting]

The photos also detail some of my experimental efforts, the framework of my successes, and the problem which is appearing for no conceivable reason.

The formula works for some cells, but after being copied and pasted with a result that reads like it should 100% work, suddenly quits working. Attempting to troubleshoot this, I deleted some cell contents/saved/re-opened the relevant documents somehow inexplicably altered the function of the output.

It returns the correct value for some cells, but zero for others after a certain numeric increment (originally 5) which changed (currently to 2) after the aforementioned troubleshooting effort.

Thanks in advance, keyboard kings.

*Edit:
I inserted new rows below cell A8 in the main sheet/workbook, and copy-pasted cell A8 (the original functional formula) into cell A9, A10, etc. - this immediately caused the copy-pasted advanced dynamic references in (now) cells A14, A15, etc. to populate with the correct data (non-0) values.... This proper functionality remained after deleting the basic external reference formulas (and entire rows) in A9:A11.

[image: Why.]

***EDIT:
...
I went to the upper right in the web version of Excel where it says "Editing"... And found in the dropdown a button, "Open in desktop app."

Upon opening both the main workbook and the reference workbook in the desktop app, I found that despite the online version of the REFERENCE book showing my changes... Somehow, at some level on the server, the original file was still intact.

***Using the desktop version, INDIRECT is functioning properly.***

If I open the faulty file in the web version, all my edits and data are shown... If I open it in the desktop version, it is displayed as the original file, before I made any edits.
What even

Comment: The screen captures and annotations are far too small. It might make sense to split them up into smaller screenshots

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If Power Query is available to you, I recommend you use Power Query.

Comment: @FlexYourData Excel 365, using OneDrive as the file location.
It is the only system that will work for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

By opening each file from the web version link to the desktop app, then saving the document by logging in with my OneDrive credentials IN the desktop app after closing the web version,
I was able to finally accomplish the functionality I needed with the INDIRECT function.

Note: There's still some wonkiness when copy-pasting the formula multiple times in rapid succession, as it is considered "volatile," and every single instance of the formula is referencing from multiple cells and two separate sheets in the home workbook, plus nested LOOKUPS and external LOOKUPS to a separate online file.